# Overriding index.html css react project

Tags: css, reactjs, components

Hopefully this is an easy one. I am working on a react project (following along with a tutorial). The repo I cloned has a custom css reference that is being applied in my index.html head here:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//demo.productionready.io/main.css">
```

I'm curious how to apply a local css file in my project directory so it overrides my external styles as I see fit.

There's a defaul index.css file that is created in my src folder via npx create-react-app. Do I need to be importing this to each react component in order to get it to work?

Thanks!

Comment: try to import in the root App.js which is parent for all the component, or add this link <link rel="stylesheet" href="//demo.productionready.io/main.css"> inside public folder public/index.html which is common

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to modify **index.html**. You can modify the default **index.css** file or delete it!

If you want to apply a local css file, import it into your component.
Or if you want a global css file, import the css file in **App.js**, it will work for all components.

> import './mycss.css';